# Saving an Array of Buttons to NSUserDefaults swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

so as the title says. is this possible? heres my code:

when leaving the view...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    defaults.setObject(buttonArray, forKey: "buttonArray")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

when entering...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce") {
        print("View already launched")

        let savedArray = defaults.arrayForKey("buttonArray")
        buttonArray = savedArray as! [UIButton]
    } else {
        print("View launched first time")        
        buttonArray = (button1, button2, button3, button4)
    }

    //rest of code where button array gets changed
}
```

im getting error `SIGNAL SIGABRT` when prepareForSegue is called

Comment: Matt, this seems like a rather easy obvious question. Have you tried it? Did it work, did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. User defaults is a property list and you can only store the following types in it (Arrays and Dictionaries can only contain those types too):

```
– NSArray
– NSData
– NSDictionary
– NSNumber
– NSString`
```

You could look into encoding your buttons into NSData, but it is bad design in my opinion. User default should be used for user preferences that should persist after the app is restarted. What information do you exactly need to recreate those buttons? Does it need to work after the app is killed or only when you reenter this screen?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, it needs to work both when switching between screens and when the app is killed/enters background etc

Comment: But do you literally need to store buttons? Why not information about how to recreate them.

Comment: would it be possible to recreate each button even though each one has a specific image and target? I tried Leo Dabus's approach but the buttons did not respond to the targets i set to them. also i declared the buttons outside of the viewDidLoad could this be a problem?

Comment: I have a gut feeling that you should use Core Data for this

Comment: @MattWyeth Also just a tip with iOS 9 you should know longer ever `synchronize` your user defaults.